# Batch print out exit code of the scipt

Tags: batch-file, scripting, exit-code

Hi lets say i have batch script that returns 0 on success and 1 on error
and i want to print/pass exiting value to console/another command

something like

`echo script param1 param2`

expected output

```
0 or 1
```

how can this be done in windws batch scripting ?

Comment: okay thats fine and is there a way to do it "on one line "? bacause now i have to run script and then echo errorlevel...

Comment: `script param1 param2 & echo %errorlevel%` - this will print the exit on one line.You can also use a conditional execution  `script param1 param2 && echo success || echo failure`

Answer (score 0):

Your script returns 0 and 1 at the moment.

Add this:

```
@ECHO off
:: script comment
cmd.exe /c somecommand
if errorlevel EQU 0 CALL script2.bat param1 param2 & goto :END
if errorlevel GEQ 1 CALL script3.bat param1 param2 & goto :ERROR
:ERROR
EXIT 1
:END
EXIT 0
```